# Format datetime axis in highcharts?

Tags: datetime, highcharts, formatting, axis-labels

http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/4537/

```
Can anyone please help with this date time axis formatting on highcharts. 
I want  Xaxis to show month only once unless the new month begins.
Like 29 April 30 1 May 2 3 4 5 
Any help would be highly appreciated
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **`xAxis.labels.formatter`** function to specify exactly what you want to show as xAxis labels:

```
labels: {
    formatter: function() {
        var date = new Date(this.value);
        var month = date.toDateString().substring(4,7);
        var day = date.getDate();

        if(this.isFirst || day == 1)
            return day + '. ' + month;

        return day;
    }
}
```

Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kp787cva/).

**EDIT:**

And if your first day of every month doesn't start from **`1`**, you can alter your code like this:

```
labels: {
    formatter: function() {
         var dateArray = this.axis.series[0].xData;
         var previousDate = new Date(dateArray[dateArray.indexOf(this.value) - 1]);
         var date = new Date(this.value);
         var month = date.toDateString().substring(4,7);
         var previousMonth = previousDate.toDateString().substring(4,7);
         var day = date.getDate();

         if(this.isFirst || (previousMonth != month))
            return day + '. ' + month;

         return day;
     }
}
```

This way you can check the previous point and if their month didn't match you can return day and month. Else only day. Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kp787cva/1/).

Comment: How would I do it , if I have the random number of days in xaxis that always dont start with 1 ?

Comment: @Hary Check the edit please. Change your data and see that it works with random days.